# Semiconductor chip shortage

Tags: integrated-circuit, semiconductors, power-engineering

Does anyone have an answer why do chip distributors have almost virtually zero stocks? Is there a shortage?[image]

Comment: I'm VTC this as it's not really about electronics.

Comment: It is about a temporary condition and answers are unlikely to be useful to future readers.

Comment: @The Photon "Temporary Condition"??

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is a shortage. There is an ongoing global pandemic that has been affecting the availability of many components for many months now.

Comment: ... years, by now.